# Base64 and XOR operation needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

I have some IV value (a URL-encoded base64 string):

```
iv = "L9CsUSgEvjM%3D"
```

Now I need to base64 decode it and then XOR only the first element of the decoded string to `'a'` and `'b'`

like

```
decoded_iv[0] ^ 'a' ^ 'b'
```

and I need to put the result of above XOR to the original `iv[0]`.

My task is:

```
decoded_iv[0] = decoded_iv[0] ^ 'a' ^ 'b'
```

But my code below is not working.

```py
iv = urllib.parse.unquote("L9CsUSgEvjM%3D");

decoded_iv = base64.b64decode(iv)

print(decoded_iv)

decoded_iv = list(decoded_iv)

print(decoded_iv)

decoded_iv[0] = str(chr(ord('a')^ord('b')^decoded_iv[0]))

decoded_iv = "".join(decoded_iv)
print(decoded_iv)
```

This prints:

```
[47, 208, 172, 81, 40, 4, 190, 51]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exploit.py", line 24, in <module>
    decoded_iv = "".join(decoded_iv)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: `ord('a')` gives you an integer.  And I actually seriously doubt that you want to convert your *number* directly into a string, as opposed to finding the *character* that the result of your XOR operation is the ordinal for.

Comment: Perhaps you want `"".join(chr(i) for i in decoded_iv)`

Comment: @JohnColeman: nope. An IV is a binary value, don't try to treat it as text.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: note that the `str()` call is simply redundant, `chr()` already returned a string.

Comment: Heh -- I didn't see the `chr()` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have found some Python 2 code, and that solution doesn't translate to Python 3. In Python 2, the data would have been a string, not a `bytes` value. `list(stringvalue)` would produce a list of characters, not a list of integers such as you have here. The `ord()` and `chr()` calls are needed in Python 2 to convert between a character in a string and its binary value (an integer between 0 and 255).

In Python 3, you don't need to do nearly as much work, because a `bytes()` object is *already* a sequence of single-byte integers. `bytesvalue[0]` gives you the integer value of the first byte:

```
>>> import urllib.parse, base64
>>> iv = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote("L9CsUSgEvjM%3D"))
>>> iv
b'/\xd0\xacQ(\x04\xbe3'
>>> iv[0]
47
```

The only remaining problem to solve is how to assign back to `iv[0]`; you can't with a `bytes()` value because that object type is immutable. That's exactly the same case for strings (which is why the Python 2 code converted from a string to a list, then used `"".join()` to convert from a list back to a string).

Instead, just use a [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray), this type gives you a mutable bytes sequence. Now you use `^` directly on the integer value at position 0.

Note that the integer value for the ASCII charater `a` is 97, and `b` is 98; these values never change and XOR is communicative (you can use the arguments in either order), so just XOR with `97 ^ 98 == 3`:

```
iv = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote("L9CsUSgEvjM%3D"))
mutable_iv = bytearray(iv)
mutable_iv[0] ^= 3  # 'a' ^ 'b' is 3
```

If you need to account for different characters, then use more `bytes()` objects and index into those to get the integer, e.g. something like `mod1, mod2 = b'a', b'b'` and `xor_mod = mod1[0] ^ mod2[0]`.

Note that there is no need to join the `bytesarray` value into a string either, the `bytesarray()` value can be used anywhere a `bytes()` value is accepted. E.g. you can encode the updated IV back to base64 and URL-encoding:

```
>>> iv = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote("L9CsUSgEvjM%3D"))
>>> mutable_iv = bytearray(iv)
>>> mutable_iv[0] ^= 3  # 'a' ^ 'b' is 3
>>> mutable_iv
bytearray(b',\xd0\xacQ(\x04\xbe3')
>>> urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(mutable_iv))
'LNCsUSgEvjM%3D'
```

Comment: Above solution worked. Thanks a lot.
Just 1 thing for clarification,we can get int of a and by by ord(a)^ord(b) = 3 , I did not understand b'a'[0] and b'b'[0]

Comment: @SACHING. `'a'` is a string object, and not a bytes sequence. `ord()` gives you the Unicode number for the given character, which happens to be the same number in ASCII or Latin-1, so `ord('a')` is 97. `b'a'` is a bytes value, where you can use ASCII characters to make it simpler to write out individual bytes that also happen to have a meaning in ASCII. So `b'a'` is a sequence of bytes, with one byte in it, whose value is `97`, and `b'a'[0]` indexes the bytes value to get that first integer out. So `ord('a') == b'a'[0]` is true, and so is `ord('b') == b'b'[0]`.